# How to get the hostname for where the azure function run from timer trigger?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a timertrigger

```
    [FunctionName("HeathChecker")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


    }
```

And an HTTP trigger

```
    [FunctionName("AspNetCoreHost")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "{*all}")]HttpRequest req,
        [AspNetCoreRunner(Startup = typeof(Startup))] IAspNetCoreRunner aspNetCoreRunner,
        ExecutionContext executionContext)
    {

        return aspNetCoreRunner.RunAsync(executionContext);
    }
```

I would like to be able to get the hostname of where the HTTP trigger is running, so I can call it with HTTP from the timer trigger. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean the URL of the function when deployed on Azure?

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the host name from the `HttpRequest req` object:

```
HostString hostString = req.Host;
string host = hostString.Host;
int? port = hostString.Port;
string fullHost = hostString.Value;
```

Comment: Anyone know where to get the `Host` for Python Functions? Trying `req.Host` results in `An exception occurred: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'Host'`

Answer (score 3):

Yo could get host name with:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")
```

You could check the value in your Function Kudu(https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net) page, select the menu "Environment", there are `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` or `SERVER_NAME`.

Comment: I was looking for a way that was using the SDK, to avoid assuming the function host was running on azure websites.

Comment: @Poul K. Sørensen, what do you mean void assuming the function host was running on azure websites? Even you run function on the local, this is still working. It   reads the  environment. And the `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` is a azure runtime environment,  so kindly you could get it only while you are using azure sdk.

Comment: The host can run on my local machine and also on other frameworks. It dont always run on azure functions. The console host writes out to logging where it listens ect, so the information must be there. Wondering if there is a dependency one can resolve that has the information.

Comment: @Poul K. Sørensen,did you mean the information store the hostname?

Comment: I found out one way to do so, making a azure function extension: https://github.com/DotNetDevOps/DotNETDevOps.Extensions.AzureFunctions/blob/dev/src/DotNETDevOps.Extensions.AzureFunctions/Startup/AspNetCoreExtension.cs#L25

Comment: @Poul K. Sørensen, have you test? What did you get?

Comment: i got the localhost:port url, it works. But looking for something where i dont need to do an extension. Would be nice to just depend on some service/class already in the framework for the function.

Comment: @Poul K. Sørensen, It's the [same output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyE9u.png) on local as the environment. Just this one uses `IWebHookProvider `. And looks like don't have to use this extension, cause it still use the webjob sdk to implement it.

Comment: Are you stateing that when doing this on azure, it also returns localhost? Thats not a problem though, the original question was about how to call the function itself from the timertrigger to keep it alive.

Comment: @Poul K. Sørensen, no, on local:port it shows local and on azure it will show site.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Thanks, i will try depend on IWebHookProvider too see if client code can get it.

Comment: @Poul K. Sørensen, if that works you could post your answer and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked this and found out that the environment variable name has changed. What's working now is this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME")
```

Comment: Just found out that my answer only gives you the subdomain part of the whole URL. So WEBSITE_HOSTNAME will give you the full domain name, while WEBSITE_SITE_NAME will just give you the first part of it. Sorry if there was any confusion.