# How to get request hostname from an HTTP-triggered, Python Azure Function request header?

Tags: python, http-headers, azure-functions, hostname

I would greatly benefit from a list of **all** the available headers that App Service can forward to my (keyword PYTHON) Function. Or if someone knows how to "list-all", that would be awesome.

Through asking questions on SO, I see that the request IP addressed can be gleaned using:

- `req.headers.get("X-FORWARDED-FOR")`.

I need the Hostname that a request is coming from.

Looks like this is possible [using C# Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56595887/10426490). But I either did it wrong using `req.headers.Host` or its not available for Python.

Is it possible using Python?

Comment: According to the documentation, headers is a dict, probably you could access host by req.headers["host"] [HttpRequest Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httprequest?view=azure-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you just need to use `req.headers.get("host")`. I test it in my side, it works fine on azure portal.
[image]